# Update JWT token field using numbus library

Tags: java, jwt, jose

I have a Signed JWT token and I need to update an existing field, let's call it `userName`. I'm using NIMBUS + JOSE and. I figured out how to parse it and extract the claims:

```
SignedJWT.parse(token)
```

but parsing is not the only thing i need: I have update the field and reassemble its token back. Is there an easy way or any kind of idiomatic solution that will work without recreating the token from scratch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I spend some time trying to figure out how to modify JWT token using the library.
And I used a quick and dirty solution:

```
// Split token into parts (parts are separated with '.'
final String[] tokenParts = token.split("\\.");

// decode payload part
final String decodedPayload =
    new String(Base64.getDecoder().decode(tokenParts[1]), "UTF-8");

// enrich payload with additional userName field by adding it to the end of
// JSON. Remove the last character which is '}' and append data as String
final String updatedDecodedPayload =
    decodedPayload.substring(0, decodedPayload.length() - 1)
    + ",\"userName\":\"" + "Richard" + "\"}";


// update payload with userId field and encode it back to base64
tokenParts[1] = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(
    updatedDecodedPayload.getBytes()
);

final String updatedToken = String.join(".", tokenParts));
```